# How to pass variable to GraphQL filter query?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to see if there is a possibility of passing variable to my query.

Here's my component **data.js**

```
export default function Data() {
    const data = useStaticQuery(
        graphql`
            query {
                allGoogleSheetDataRow(filter: { state: { eq: "ALABAMA" } }) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            snap
                            tanf
                            medicaid
                            unemployment
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `
    );
    return (
    .
    .
    . 
    .
    );
}
```

then

```
import DATA from './src/components/data'

<DATA />
```

That's what I'm currently doing and it's fine if it is only one page. I think the right approach to make the component 'reusable' so here I'd like to know how do I pass variable to my filter

`allGoogleSheetDataRow(filter: { state: { eq: "--- some variable --" } })`

so I could import it with

```
import DATA from './src/components/data'

<DATA state="ALABAMA" />
```

Could someone in the know point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `useStaticQuery` rather than a page query. According to the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/#how-to-add-query-variables-to-a-page-query):

**"Variables can be added to page queries (but not static queries) through the context object that is an argument of the createPage API."**

So, you don't need to import `useStaticQuery`. Simply import graphql. Then, add this after your component:

```
export const query = graphql`
        query DataQuery($state: String) {
            allGoogleSheetDataRow(filter: { state: { eq: $state } }) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        snap
                        tanf
                        medicaid
                        unemployment
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `
```

Then pass `data` to your components parameters

```
export default function YourComponent({data}) { 
      // Access data object here.
}
```

I didn't include passing the variable within context in the `gatsby-node.js` file. However, you'll have to do that as well. There's an example of how to do this in the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gatsby, which I assume is where `useStaticQuery` comes from, then you can't. The `Static` there in the name means you can't use a variable in them. Sadly :(

You can probably read more about it here: https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/using-variables-in-a-staticquery~abee4d1d-6bc4-4202-afb2-38326d91bd05

---

Alternativelly, you could create a custom "useQuery", which is a fancy way to name a function that returns a value. ;)

For this you have:

```js
const useCustomQuery = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
          allGoogleSheetDataRow(filter: { state: { eq: "ALABAMA" } }) {
              edges {
                  node {
                      snap
                      tanf
                      medicaid
                      unemployment
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    `
  );
  return data
}
```

and in your "page" or any component you need data, you just need to use

```
const Component = () => {
  const data = useCustomQuery()

  // use data anyway you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @jcquintas. Actually, I'm using the method mentioned in the article you shared for my reusable `header` component but for this specific issue I couldn't apply the same to the `filter`. Not quite sure if it is making sense to repeat the same query on every page for now.

Comment: You can always create a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) so you only use 2 lines of code in each subsequent component or page that you need it, `import` and `useCustomQuery`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. Would be kind enough to give some example on how to use `useCustomQuery`?

Comment: I added an alternate solution to the answer above, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide the solution but then the filter parameter is _not dynamic_. It will only filter the state of "ALABAMA", will it not? What I'm trying to achieve is to query the data based on the state the page is about, meaning if the page is about New York, I will only query "New York".